# Can't get Susy based grid to align properly

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I have been trying out the [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) plugin for [Compass](http://compass-style.org) ([SASS](http://sass-lang.com)), but I noticed that it isn't working as intended for me.

I took the `index.html` and `screen.scss` from the [official Susy tutorial](http://susy.oddbird.net/tutorial/), compiled the SCSS and put it up on [my server](http://spielwiese.mobweb.ch/so/original/). As you can see it looks just like it's supposed to (on all browsers I tested it on):

[image]

What I did next was the following:

- Copy the `<article>` in the `<div role="main">` and paste it six times
- In `screen.scss`, change the column-span (`div[role="main"] > article`) accordingly: from `@include columns(6,9);` to `@include columns(1,9);`

But now those new elements don't align to the grid at all, they are off by a clearly visible  space. I tested this in recent versions of FF, Safari and Chrome, and only FF seems to display it correctly. Screenshot is from Chrome:

[image]

I also uploaded the source for everyone to inspect [here](http://spielwiese.mobweb.ch/so/modified/).

Is this a general problem with Susy that the grid isn't correct or am I doing something wrong? If the first, does anybody know a workaround? I also tried with percentages and pixels, but neither worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Susy isn't just another grid system like all the others. It was designed to fulfill a very specific purpose: grids that are [fluid on the inside](https://github.com/ericam/compass-susy-plugin/blob/master/README.mkdn). The units you use to create the grid are applied to the container, not to each column. Everything inside is built with percentages. What you are seeing is normal. It's true of all fluid grids, because of [sub-pixel rounding](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/). It's not a bug, it's a part of building responsive web sites.

If you need pixel-exact grids, Susy is the wrong tool for you. It all depends what you are trying to build.

Re-size your browser to see how it works. You'll notice the grids snapping-to and floating within a few pixels of their guides, but the grid stays intact and never triggers the horizontal scroll-bar.

Cheers!

-e

Comment: (In your case, the more often you round-down the same sub-pixel math, the more "off" your grid will seem. Your demo takes the browser's single-pixel deviation, and multiplies that till it's noticeable.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link explaining the behavior. I don't need pixel-exact positioning, but I am still unsure about one thing: Suppose I have another container below the 6 `<article>`, starting at column 9 and spanning all the way to the right. How would I make sure that it aligns properly on the left-hand side to the last `article`? Or is that not possible and should I change my design accordingly?

Comment: There's no simple answer there. It all depends on the setup. If both are `omega` columns, and you leave `$omega-float` set to the right, you can get them to line up by making them measure from the other side (so they aren't affected by the multiplied rounding.